# How can I retrieve a column value of a specific row

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

The table `partner.partner_statistic` contains the following columns:

```
  id     reg_count
serial    integer
```

I wrote the function convert(integer):

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert(d integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
--Do something and return integer result
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And now I need to write a function returned array of integers as follows:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION res() RETURNS integer[] AS $$
    << outerblock >>
    DECLARE
        arr integer[]; --That array of integers I need to fill in depends on the result of query
        r partner.partner_statistic%rowtype;
        table_name varchar DEFAULT 'partner.partner_statistic';
    BEGIN
        FOR r IN 
        SELECT * FROM partner.partner_statistic offset 0 limit 100
        LOOP
        --
        -- I need to add convert(r[reg_count]) to arr where r[id] = 0 (mod 5)
        --
        -- How can I do that?
        END LOOP;
        RETURN;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need (and shouldn't use) PL/PgSQL loops for this. Just use an aggregate. I'm kind of guessing about what you mean by "`where r[id] = 0 (mod 5)` but I'm assuming you mean *"where id is evenly divisible by 5"*. (Note that this is NOT the same thing as *"every fifth row"* because generated IDs have gaps).

Something like:

```
SELECT array_agg(r.reg_count) 
FROM partner.partner_statistic
WHERE id % 5 = 0
LIMIT 100
```

probably meets your needs.

If you want to return the value, use `RETURN QUERY SELECT ...` or preferably use a simple sql language function.

If you want a dynamic table name, use:

```
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
    SELECT array_agg(r.reg_count) 
    FROM %I
    WHERE id % 5 = 0
    LIMIT 100', table_name::regclass);
```

Comment: But I need a FUNCTION, returned an array.

Comment: @St.Antario You can wrap a plain query in an sql function.  Or use PL/pgSQL; that's why I pointed out `RETURN QUERY`. I haven't written the whole function body in the answer, just the bit that shows you how to collect the array without any messy looping.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm also would like to know is it possible to access to the value of a specific column of the row `r`, which I use in FOR-LOOP? In general I mean what can we do with a variable of `table_name%rowtype`?

Comment: @St.Antario sure, all fields are accessible, use `r.fieldname` e.g. `r.id`